# Unit-testing method invocation (template method)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

Is it possible to unit-test method invocation on the *same class*(in order and how many times they were invoked) ?

i.e. A Template Method like the one below:

```
    abstract class FooBarBaz {

       public abstract void foo();
       public abstract void bar();
       public abstract void baz();

       // I want to create a unit test for this method, in the following order
       public myTemplateMethod() {
          foo();  // i want to check foo first;
          bar();  // i want to check bar second;
          baz();  // i want to check baz third;
       }
    }
```

EDIT - Posted Mockito Code Implementation

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class FooBarBazTest extends TestCase {

   public void testMyTemplateMethodWithMockito() {
      FooBarBaz mocked = Mockito.mock(FooBarBaz.class);

      mocked.myTemplateMethod();

      Mockito.verify(mocked, Mockito.times(1)).foo();
      Mockito.verify(mocked, Mockito.times(1)).bar();
      Mockito.verify(mocked, Mockito.times(1)).baz();
   }
}
```

EDIT - Added Stack Trace

```
testMyTemplateMethodWithMockito(sample.FooBarBazTest)  Time elapsed: 0.326 sec  <<< FAILURE!
Wanted but not invoked:
fooBarBaz.foo();
-> at sample.FooBarBazTest.testMyTemplateMethodWithMockito(FooBarBazTest.java:14)

However, there were other interactions with this mock:
-> at sample.FooBarBazTest.testMyTemplateMethodWithMockito(FooBarBazTest.java:12)

    at sample.FooBarBazTest.testMyTemplateMethodWithMockito(FooBarBazTest.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a mocking framework is fine, but if you don't want to rely upon an external dependency, simply create a test class that implements your abstract class.  Have the abstract implementations of the foo, bar, baz method add the strings 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' to a shared list, then in your test method just assert they are in the list in the correct order.

EDIT -- Ive written the tests both with mockito and the non-mock way.  They both pass--I hadn't used mockito before, I might want to try it....

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FooBarBazTests extends TestCase {


    @Test
    public void testMyTemplateMethod() {
        List tracker = new ArrayList();
        SimpleFooBarBaz toTest = new SimpleFooBarBaz(tracker);

        toTest.myTemplateMethod();


        assertEquals("foo", tracker.get(0));

        // more assertions
    }


    @Test
    public void testMyTemplateMethodWithMockito() {
        FooBarBaz mocked = mock(FooBarBaz.class);

        mocked.myTemplateMethod();

        // times(1) is unnecessary, but explicit
        verify(mocked, times(1)).foo();
        verify(mocked, times(1)).bar();
        verify(mocked, times(1)).baz();
    }

    class SimpleFooBarBaz extends FooBarBaz {


        List tracker;

        SimpleFooBarBaz(List tracker) {
            this.tracker = tracker;
        }

        public void foo() {
            tracker.add("foo");
        }

        @Override
        public void bar() {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void baz() {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        // others there

    }

}
```

Comment: @hvgotcodes Thanks, that certainly is a way to check it but it would add unnecessary lines of code when looking outside the test context. Are there cleaner ways to do this?

Comment: @Joopiter I dont understand what you mean by 'unnecessary lines of code'.  I think this approach is about as simple as it gets without using a mocking framework...

Comment: @hvgotcodes 'unnecessary lines of code' means that I would need to create an instance of a list(tracker in this case) which sole purpose is to test and does not contribute to the part of the business logic. But it made sense that this class sole purpose is for testing method invocations only. I just need to add some minor modifications for checking the order of method invocations. Thanks

Comment: @joopiter, right, but that is only in the test implementation.  The original class remains unblemished.  I highly recommend that you do NOT track method invocation order in the class under test, unless it is part of the normal business logic of that class.

Comment: @hvgotcodes the mockito version didn't work in my case the error was "Wanted but not invoked"(This is what i'm referring to in my comment with @javamonkey) I'm using version 1.8.5 of Mockito. However the plain implementation worked fine.

Comment: @joopiter weird it worked for me...in your case, the test is failing, and indicating that you verified a method that did not actually get invoked.  I would double check to make sure.  You might have found a bug in your code ;)

Comment: @hvgotcodes thanks for the advice, yes it's part of the business logic.

Comment: @hvgotcodes may I know which mockito version you used? I used the maven artifact defined in here: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/mockito/mockito-all/1.8.5/mockito-all-1.8.5.pom

Comment: @hvgotcodes no luck, I tried switching version and results are still the same, guess ill have to live without Mockito. Man it's much cleaner if it worked that way...

Comment: @joopiter, post the code, it is clean and it should work.  this is an easy case.

Comment: @joopiter, you might want to post the error too, and a description of why you are editing -- I didnt realize you just copied the answer (which is ok), I thought you might have a different class.  Does it work when you run the tests in your ide without maven?

Comment: @hvgotcodes the error is posted (along with the trace), i copied it to avoid other issues that might be cause the problem. Unfortunately, it didn't work on both my terminal and ide(eclipse)

Comment: @joopiter the only other thing i can think of is add import static org.mockito.Mockito.*; -- i have that in mine but it didn't make it into the copy paste over to SO.  You might want to start another question on why that is failing.

Comment: @hvgotcodes thanks, i'll just go with the plain implementation for now.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) it has this behavior built into it.

From their documentation:
6. Verification in order

```
 List firstMock = mock(List.class);
 List secondMock = mock(List.class);

 //using mocks
 firstMock.add("was called first");
 secondMock.add("was called second");

 //create inOrder object passing any mocks that need to be verified in order
 InOrder inOrder = inOrder(firstMock, secondMock);

 //following will make sure that firstMock was called before secondMock
 inOrder.verify(firstMock).add("was called first");
 inOrder.verify(secondMock).add("was called second");
```

And:
4. Verifying exact number of invocations / at least x / never

```
 //using mock 
 mockedList.add("once");

 mockedList.add("twice");
 mockedList.add("twice");

 mockedList.add("three times");
 mockedList.add("three times");
 mockedList.add("three times");

 //following two verifications work exactly the same - times(1) is used by default
 verify(mockedList).add("once");
 verify(mockedList, times(1)).add("once");

 //exact number of invocations verification
 verify(mockedList, times(2)).add("twice");
 verify(mockedList, times(3)).add("three times");

 //verification using never(). never() is an alias to times(0)
 verify(mockedList, never()).add("never happened");

 //verification using atLeast()/atMost()
 verify(mockedList, atLeastOnce()).add("three times");
 verify(mockedList, atLeast(2)).add("five times");
 verify(mockedList, atMost(5)).add("three times");
```

Comment: @javamonkey79 the problem with this is i need to invoke the methods within my test case in order to see if it was invoked.

Comment: @joopiter, i think he is just showing you documentation, you will need to mock your abstract class, set up the expectations, and call your method-to-test, and then verify

Comment: @javamonkey79 -- im not sure mockito can verify the order of the method calls ON THE SAME MOCK.  my mockito test below is incorrect in that it passes if i change the order of the calls in the class under test.

Comment: @javamonkey79 -- i figured it out...;)